# How to access two array elements at once

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of User objects: @users = User.all.  Now I would like to populate a two column table with something like this.  But the following code doesn't work. It's telling me `first_name` is an undefined method. (I also don't know how to skip an iteration):

```
<table class="member_table">
  <% for i in 0..@users.length %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @users[i].first_name %></td>
      <td><%= @users[i+1].first_name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% skip one iteration %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

The `each_slice` method turns your array into an array of 'slices', the size of which you specify as the first parameter, like so:

```
(0...10).each_slice(2).to_a
=> [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Using your example, you'd end up with:

```
<table class="member_table">
  <% @users.each_slice(2) do |first_user, second_user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= first_user.first_name %></td>
      <td><%= second_user.first_name unless second_user.nil? %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: `@users.each_slice(2) do |first, second|` to unpack the element pair~

Comment: Totally. Silly oversight on my behalf there. Also added a conditional to the second bit of output, in case there's an odd-number of users in the collection.

Comment: I don't even think I could write `for` loop in Ruby if I wanted to! :)

Answer (score 0):

Next time, post the full text of the error message.

You're going beyond the array bounds and trying to dereference `nil`. `nil` has no method `first_name`.

Suppose you have two users in your array, U0 and U1. Your array now has length two.

You're now looping over this array:

- i = 0, and you print U0 and U1
- i = 1, and you print U1 and try and print U2, which doesn't exist

Comment: And the fix for going past the end of the array is what? It'd be good to cover why `for` is not idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely go with theTRON's solution. However in your case the exception is triggered when you try to acess `@users[N]` where `N >= @users.length`

For example :

```
test = [1,2,3]
test[1]     # => 2
test.length # => 3
test[3]     # => not defined
```